# Android Osmdroid Polygons deformation on scrolling

Tags: polygon, android-mapview, osmdroid

Hi I'm using Osmdroid library to build polygons on a map (Image : [Polygons on a MapView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vjlCT.png)) using a Kml file that I am parsing. I am building a list of placemarks from my Kml and then I am building my polygons and adding them to my mapView. Ie.

```
private void createPolygones() {
    // Build polygon and load them on the map
    // list to retrieve the correct answer when we need it
    polygonList = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int j = 0; j < placemarks.size(); j++) {
        List<GeoPoint> myGeoList = new ArrayList<>();
        Placemark placemark = placemarks.get(j);
        // get all coordinate of the placemark
        for (int i = 0; i < placemark.getCoordinates().size(); i++) {
            myGeoList.add(new GeoPoint(placemark.getCoordinates().get(i)
                    .getLatitude(), placemark.getCoordinates().get(i)
                    .getLongitude()));
        }
        CustomPolygon polygon = new CustomPolygon(this);
        Log.d(TAG,"polygon point list : " + myGeoList);
        polygon.setPoints(myGeoList);
        polygon.initDefaultColor();
        polygon.setTitle(placemark.getName());
        polygonList.add(polygon);
        map.getOverlays().add(polygon);
    }
}
```

Everything is going well, except that I encountered a strange bug, when scrolling to another place of the map, new polygons draw themselves on wrong positions and I can't explain it. (See Image: [Polygon Bug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xrCqF.png))
Small hint, when I click the polygons, they are the one I built earlier.

Any help would be useful!

Comment: What is a "CustomPolygon"? Test using regular osmdroid Polygon. If KO, please provide a sample (with coordinates).

Comment: My class CustomPolygon is a simple polygon that Overrides onSingleTapConfirmed to handle the click on a polygon.

class CustomPolygon extends Polygon {
    @Override
    public boolean onSingleTapConfirmed(final MotionEvent event, final MapView mapView) {
                flashColors(FILL_COLOR_FOUND, true);
       }
        return tapped;
    }
}


I removed the custom class and used only polygons, I get the same problem.

Comment: Looks like you found the date line bug.